# Load error on rails new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rvm

Unable to create a new rails application, when I run `rails new app`, I got following error

```
/home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.3/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

My gem env

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/mr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/mr/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/mr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
     - /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /home/mr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
     - /home/mr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /home/mr/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

In my gem list I have rails 4.2.3 gem

I tried `rvm use 2.2.0` and `/bin/bash --login` also re-installed rails gem but nothing works, how to fix this issue?

Comment: For kicks try `sudo rails new myapp`. Just wondering if it could be something wonky with file rights and your RVM install.